# Getting error Bad File Descriptor while installing pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, packageinstaller

whenever i try to install pip i always get this error. pls help . i dont know how to fix this i tried doing it using the default python executable using the modify method and also tried the get-pip.py file method nothing works. i have checked my path variables too so the scripts folder is there but pip is not installed.

```
    PS C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\programs\PYTHON> python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\programs\PYTHON\get-pip.py", line 23704, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\programs\PYTHON\get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\programs\PYTHON\get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz82tcza4\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 786, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 980, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: what was your command?

Comment: i was installing pip by python get-pip.py

Comment: The "bad file descriptor" is just fallout from the endless loop where it opens the same file again and again. It runs out of file descriptors eventually, which is good insofar as that finally breaks the loop.

Comment: If you have Python 3.9 you already _have_ `pip`.

Comment: i have tried running pip many time and every time it returns that pip is not recognized as a command , script etc

Comment: i have checked the scripts folder of python too but its empty and here is no pip i guess it was supposed to be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i tried unistalling this new version(3.9) and then installed an old version(3.7) and then ran the command `python get-pip.py` and magically it worked. if anyone in future wants to fix this issue then try this. i also read the python documenttion and apparantly they have a command if pip isnt installed on your version of python that is `python -m ensurepip` so you can try that too.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar problem and tried every possible solution, the only one which worked with me is to uninstall python and reinstall it in different partition other than the C , it will work !

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder in which you Python installer is there and click on it. It will open the installer and show "modify setup":

[image: Screenshot of Python install wizard on top of PyCharm]

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall python and then download it from https://www.python.org/downloads/ reinstall it and make sure to check the box that adds pip to PATH.

[image]

Comment: sadly my python is already added to path and im using python 3.9 the latest version is it related to that?

Comment: and what happens when you type pip --version?

Comment: it just returns pip isnt recognized as a command error

Answer (score 0):

In a python virtual environment, venv, I was using pip freeze to save requirements when I got an "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor".  It turned out the my Norton antivirus protection found pip to be suspicious and was blocking it.  After excluding pip.exe in Norton, that is letting Norton know it was not a threat, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later and this issue arises for a different reason. Leaving this answer here to help others.

If you encounter "Bad File Descriptor" when using Python, Pip or Poetry on Windows:

It is possible that Windows Security is blocking access to your files. It may do this as part of Controlled Folder Access, as part of Virus & Threat Protection. If this is the cause of the problem, the solution is to allow Python to access your documents. (The solution is *not* to turn off virus and threat protection. You can solve this without having to give up on anti-virus.)

Steps:

1. Open Windows Security
2. Go to Virus & Threat Protection
3. Go to Virus & Threat Protection Settings (by clicking Manage Settings)
4. Scroll down to find Controlled Folder Access
5. Click Manage Controlled folder access
6. Is is turned on? If no, stop here as this can't be the cause of the issue. If yes, proceed.
7. Open the Block History
8. Inspect the list of blocked folder accesses. Do you see a recent entry for `python.exe` trying to access the folder you were working in? If no, stop here as controlled folder access is not the cause of the issue. If yes, proceed.
9. Go back to Manage Controlled folder access
10. Click "Allow an app through Controlled folder access"
11. Click "Add an allowed app"
12. Click "Recently blocked apps"
13. You should see Python in the list. Click on it and allow it through. (If not, click "Add an allowed app" then use "Browse all apps" to manually find python.exe -- from a command prompt (not powershell), use `where python.exe` to discover Python's location.)
14. You're done. Retry using python/pip/poetry.

Good luck!

---

Footnote:

This is not the only possible cause of Bad File Descriptor. The above steps tell you to stop if you don't find the logs which tell you if Controlled Folder Access is the cause of your problem. Please don't add Python to your exclusion list if it's not the cause of your problem as that just risks opening you up to viruses in the future.

Answer (score -1):

And then click on "Uninstall". After uninstall done click on close and again go to your installer and click on it and after that it will show [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmpaG.png)

Comment: You will need to, as another contributor has mentioned, combine your 3 answers to this question. I believe that your answer is great, it is just disjointed and is unlikely to continue to help other people experiencing similar issues down the line if it is split into 3 different answers, each with only part of the info, and only one can be selected as correct.

Answer (score -1):

After check Add python to PATH and click on "customize installation". Check everything in advanced option and click install.

Done!

Comment: You have posted [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72026544/354577) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72026474/354577) answers to this question that appear to be related to each other. Stack Overflow isn't a forum, it is a question and answer site. Each answer must be an answer to the question, not _part of_ an answer to the question. Posts are usually displayed in a different order than they are posted. Please take the [tour], read [answer], then edit one of your answers to be complete and delete the other two.